# SQL Server - moved index behind PK constraint to different filegroup, but space not freed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, primary-key

I have a large table Foo.  There are 4 filegroups (FG1, FG2, FG3, FG4)

FG2 is on a disk that is nearly full.  It has 2 indexes:

a) clustered index (on Date)
b) a unique non-clustered index (on ID)

There is a PK constraint on the table, on ID.

I wanted to move index (b) from FG2 to a different file group - FG4.

First I tried simply builiding a second index, like (b), on FG4, then dropping (b).  This failed - An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index due to the PK.

So I went ahead and rebuilt it on the new filegroup:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX PK_Foo
ON Foo(ID)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING =  ON, PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = 
ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
ON [FG4]
```

This succeeded. I can see the index is now definitely on FG4, all is well.
However, no space has been freed up on FG2 at all. If I try to shrink FG2, it shows no space within it is free.

Where has my space gone?

Thanks!

Update - Index sys.data_spaces:

FileGropName    ObjectName  IndexType   IndexName   type_desc   Mb

FG3 Foo NONCLUSTERED    IX_Foo_CorrelationId    IN_ROW_DATA 193802

FG3 Foo NONCLUSTERED    IX_Foo_DeviceIntId  IN_ROW_DATA 97676

FG3 Foo NONCLUSTERED    IX_Foo_DrtId_RC_CorrelationId   IN_ROW_DATA 286386

FG2 Foo CLUSTERED   IX_Foo_LastResponse IN_ROW_DATA 468845

FG4 Foo NONCLUSTERED    PK_Foo  IN_ROW_DATA 104377

Comment: Did you try DBCC SHRINKFILE notruncate before DBCC SHRINKFILE truncateonly?

Comment: I have not actually tried to execute DBCC SHRINKFILE.  Only looked at the files via SSMS, where it shows you the % free in the file, which normally works very well for me.  It shows 0% free in FG2.

Comment: Ok, so your index was effectively moved to FG4, but did you really try to shrink or only "looked at the files via SSMS"?

Comment: Other than shrinkfile, you can use this script to find out free space in your files: select
   name AS FileName, 
   size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB, 
   size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB 
from sys.database_files;

Comment: Only looked at it in SSMS.  That query shows the same:  FG1 454995.625000 381132.437500
Foo_log 75073.000000 74915.898438
FG2 468976.000000 82.000000
FG3 680168.000000 102242.312500
FG4 104528.000000 149.250000

Comment: At this point I think you'd better check all the space in FG2 object by object, for example using the script I posted before, without filtering by object, instead filtering by DS.name (FGName)

Comment: Thanks. There is only the expected CI in that output for FG2.  The size is 469077.   For FG4, I see the NCI index, 104377 big.  So according to this output, things seems sane...except for the fact that the NCI index has been moved, and no space freed up in FG2.   Its like the NCI was piggybacking on the CI somehow when it was on FG2. Now its on FG4 its taking its own space, in addition.  But I don't have a mental model for how that could be.

Comment: Excuse me, but I cannot see a problem, your clustered index is about 468,845Mb, your File size (for FG2) is 468,976Mb, so it's full. What was the File size for FG2 *before* you moved the nonclustered index? If it was 100Gb more than now, it means someone did a shrink, maybe it was you

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned - the disk FG2 is on, is only 500 gigs.  So it would be impossible for it to be 568. I don't recall the exactly size, but it was about 90% full before the move - so 450 for both CI and NCI...  thanks.

Comment: So - is it possible that `PK_Foo` wasn't actually in FG2? If the total size of the CI and `PK_Foo` is greater than could fit in FG2, then the logical conclusion is that `PK_Foo` wasn't actually in FG2.

Comment: Follow your logic, but we know drive with FG2 was at 90% for sure.   We moved index to another drive - which definitely is 100 gig on destination drive.  Original drive still roughly 90% full, with content.    Still have the scripts which rehearsed the move, which showed the NCI on FG2. Sounds crazy I know.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a unique key on your primary key. You should be able to drop the PK constraint itself and then create it again on the new file group.

Comment: Also, if you aren't convinced that your CI is taking up all that space, then rebuild it. I'd agree with the others that your index PK_Foo was not on FG2 to begin with.

Comment: Rebuilding the CI will take forever, causing all the NCIs to be rebuilt, and be an offline operation.... so reluctant to do so.    Do you perhaps know if using DBCC shrinkfile (emptyfile) would still be an online operation, and/or cause the NCIs to be rebuilt, if the source file contained a CI?

Comment: I'm confused about the primary key, perhaps you are as well.  A genuine primary key is a Constraint and created or dropped as such; the index comes with it.  Since it's non-clustered in this case, it's independent of other indexes, except the clustered index.  I would think however that you might have just duplicated the Primary Key with an index that just happens to be named "PK_Foo" but with your actual Primary Key also still existing in FG2 - except I think you shouldn't be able to do that with the same index name.  Would it hurt to run DBCC CHECKDB()...

Answer (score 0):

Space in FG2 used by objects:

```
SELECT DS.name AS FileGropName 
      ,OBJ.name AS ObjectName
      ,IDX.type_desc AS IndexType 
      ,IDX.name AS IndexName 
      ,AU.type_desc
      ,AU.total_pages * 8 / 1024 AS Mb
FROM sys.data_spaces AS DS 
     INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS AU 
         ON DS.data_space_id = AU.data_space_id 
     INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS PA 
         ON (AU.type IN (1, 3)  
             AND AU.container_id = PA.hobt_id) 
            OR 
            (AU.type = 2 
             AND AU.container_id = PA.partition_id) 
     INNER JOIN sys.objects AS OBJ 
         ON PA.object_id = OBJ.object_id 
     INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS IDX 
         ON PA.object_id = IDX.object_id 
            AND PA.index_id = IDX.index_id 
WHERE DS.name = 'FG2'
ORDER BY AU.total_pages DESC
```